# How can I use/print abstract field as annotation with philosophy-modern.bbx?

Tags: biblatex, biber, biblatex-philosophy

In my very, very long bibliography I use the field `abstract` for real abstracts, which means in turn that I can't print them as `abstracts`, but only if I disguise them as `annotation`, which `philosophy-modern.bbx` knows. So I'd like to know: how can I convince `biblatex` that it's not dealing with `abstracts` but with `annotations`, so that it prints them?

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures+[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{Ligatures={TeX,Common}}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella X}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern, sortlocale=auto, sorting=nyvt,%
            alldates=terse, annotation=true, abstract, % <--???
            language=ngerman, bibencoding=utf8,%
            backend=biber, autolang=hyphen, 
                                          clearlang=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{AbstractBibliographie.bib}
\begin{filecontents*}{AbstractBibliographie.bib}
@Book{Adams:SocratesMystagogos,
  author =   {Don Adams},
  gender =   {sm},
  title =    {Socrates Mystagogos},
  langid =   {english},
  year =     2017,
  publisher =    {Routledge},
  location =     {Abingdon, OX, AND New York},
  doi =      {10.4324/9781315609812},
  abstract =     {\autocap from the blurb \mkbibquote{For Socrates,
                  philosophy is not like Christian conversion from
                  error to truth, but rather it is like the pagan
                  process whereby a young man is initiated into cult
                  mysteries by a more experienced
                  man\addthinspace--\addthinspace the
                  mystagogos\addthinspace--\addthinspace who prepares
                  him and leads him to the sacred precinct. In Greek
                  cult religion, the mystagogos prepared the initiate
                  for the esoteric mysteries revealed by the
                  hierophant. Socrates treats traditional wisdom with
                  scepticism, and this makes him appear ridiculous or
                  dangerous in the eyes of cultural
                  conservatives. Nevertheless, his scepticism is not
                  radical: custom is not something on which we must
                  turn our backs if we are to pursue the
                  truth. Socrates assumes an epistemology and employs
                  a method by which he induces his companions to begin
                  the critical and self-critical process of
                  philosophical inquiry, not ignoring conventional
                  wisdom, but thinking through and reinterpreting it
                  as they make constructive progress towards the
                  truth. He provides conclusive and convincing
                  arguments in support of controversial answers to
                  some of the most important moral questions he
                  poses.}}}

@Article{Adluri:Initiation,
  author =   {Vishwa Adluri},
  gender =   {sm},
  title =    {Initiation into the Mysteries},
  shorttitle =   {Initiation},
  langid =   {english},
  journaltitle = {Mouseion},
  year =     2006,
  issuetitle =   {\mkbibparens{Ir}rationality in the Ancient World},
  series =   3,
  volume =   6,
  number =   3,
  pages =    {407-423},
  eprint =   {http://digital.utpjournals.com/i/319761},
  abstract =     {\mkbibquote{\selectlanguage{french}Les dialogues de Platon soulignent la
                  transformation personnelle et le salut tels qu'on
                  les trouvait dans \mkbibquote{l'initiation aux
                  mystères}. Burkert, Kingsley et Riedweg, en suivant
                  les traces de Damascius et des Néoplatoniciens, ont
                  récemment démontré les aspects théologiques,
                  existentiels et sotériologiques chez
                  Platon. Celui-ci exploite à son profit non seulement
                  le vocabulaire et l'organisation des rites
                  d'initiation mais aussi leur aspect
                  \mkbibquote{expérience vécue}. Ainsi Socrate: après
                  avoir désorienté ses interlocuteurs par la
                  dialectique, leur révèle les \mkbibquote{mystères}
                  au moyen de mythes grandioses qui représentent
                  rapogée de l'expérience philosophique. Celle-ci
                  confère une assurance intrépide devant la mort et
                  accorde le salut en montrant l'univers du point de
                  vue de l'éternelle raison
                  \mkbibparens{\mkbibemph{nous}}. Elle lave le
                  philosophe de toute identité politique et
                  idéologique.}}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution if you don't plan on using `annotation` is to have Biber remap all `abstract` fields to `annotation`. Since the style prints `annotation` we get the desired result.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures+[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{Ligatures={TeX,Common}}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella X}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern, sortlocale=auto, sorting=nyvt,%
            alldates=terse, annotation=true, % <--???
            language=ngerman, bibencoding=utf8,%
            backend=biber, autolang=hyphen, 
                                          clearlang=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=abstract, fieldtarget=annotation]
    }
  }
}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Adams:SocratesMystagogos,
  author =   {Don Adams},
  gender =   {sm},
  title =    {Socrates Mystagogos},
  langid =   {english},
  year =     2017,
  publisher =    {Routledge},
  location =     {Abingdon, OX, AND New York},
  doi =      {10.4324/9781315609812},
  abstract =     {\autocap{f}rom the blurb \mkbibquote{For Socrates,
                  philosophy is not like Christian conversion from
                  error to truth, but rather it is like the pagan
                  process whereby a young man is initiated into cult
                  mysteries by a more experienced
                  man\addthinspace--\addthinspace the
                  mystagogos\addthinspace--\addthinspace who prepares
                  him and leads him to the sacred precinct. In Greek
                  cult religion, the mystagogos prepared the initiate
                  for the esoteric mysteries revealed by the
                  hierophant. Socrates treats traditional wisdom with
                  scepticism, and this makes him appear ridiculous or
                  dangerous in the eyes of cultural
                  conservatives. Nevertheless, his scepticism is not
                  radical: custom is not something on which we must
                  turn our backs if we are to pursue the
                  truth. Socrates assumes an epistemology and employs
                  a method by which he induces his companions to begin
                  the critical and self-critical process of
                  philosophical inquiry, not ignoring conventional
                  wisdom, but thinking through and reinterpreting it
                  as they make constructive progress towards the
                  truth. He provides conclusive and convincing
                  arguments in support of controversial answers to
                  some of the most important moral questions he
                  poses.}}}

@Article{Adluri:Initiation,
  author =   {Vishwa Adluri},
  gender =   {sm},
  title =    {Initiation into the Mysteries},
  shorttitle =   {Initiation},
  langid =   {english},
  journaltitle = {Mouseion},
  year =     2006,
  issuetitle =   {\mkbibparens{Ir}rationality in the Ancient World},
  series =   3,
  volume =   6,
  number =   3,
  pages =    {407-423},
  eprint =   {http://digital.utpjournals.com/i/319761},
  abstract =     {\mkbibquote{\selectlanguage{french}Les dialogues de Platon soulignent la
                  transformation personnelle et le salut tels qu'on
                  les trouvait dans \mkbibquote{l'initiation aux
                  mystères}. Burkert, Kingsley et Riedweg, en suivant
                  les traces de Damascius et des Néoplatoniciens, ont
                  récemment démontré les aspects théologiques,
                  existentiels et sotériologiques chez
                  Platon. Celui-ci exploite à son profit non seulement
                  le vocabulaire et l'organisation des rites
                  d'initiation mais aussi leur aspect
                  \mkbibquote{expérience vécue}. Ainsi Socrate: après
                  avoir désorienté ses interlocuteurs par la
                  dialectique, leur révèle les \mkbibquote{mystères}
                  au moyen de mythes grandioses qui représentent
                  rapogée de l'expérience philosophique. Celle-ci
                  confère une assurance intrépide devant la mort et
                  accorde le salut en montrant l'univers du point de
                  vue de l'éternelle raison
                  \mkbibparens{\mkbibemph{nous}}. Elle lave le
                  philosophe de toute identité politique et
                  idéologique.}}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with long abstracts.]

If you'd rather be able to use `annotation` and `abstract` together, we have to fiddle with the `finentry` bibmacro, which is where `biblatex-philosophy` prints `annotation`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures+[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{Ligatures={TeX,Common}}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella X}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern, sortlocale=auto, sorting=nyvt,%
            alldates=terse, annotation=true, % <--???
            language=ngerman, bibencoding=utf8,%
            backend=biber, autolang=hyphen, 
                                          clearlang=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtoggle{bbx:abstract}
\toggletrue{bbx:abstract}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ifannotation}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:annotation}
    {\iffieldundef{annotation}
       {\@secondoftwo}
       {\@firstoftwo}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}

\newcommand*{\ifabstract}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:abstract}
    {\iffieldundef{abstract}
       {\@secondoftwo}
       {\@firstoftwo}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\abstractfont}{\annotationfont}
\DeclareFieldFormat{abstract}{\annotationfont #1}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifannotation} or test {\ifabstract}}
    {\setunit{\addperiod\par\nobreak\vspace*{.5ex}}%
     \printfield{annotation}%
     \setunit{\addperiod\par\nobreak\vspace*{.5ex}}%
     \printfield{abstract}%
     \finentry}
    {\finentry}}


\begin{filecontents*}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Adams:SocratesMystagogos,
  author =   {Don Adams},
  gender =   {sm},
  title =    {Socrates Mystagogos},
  langid =   {english},
  year =     2017,
  publisher =    {Routledge},
  location =     {Abingdon, OX, AND New York},
  doi =      {10.4324/9781315609812},
  abstract =     {\autocap{f}rom the blurb \mkbibquote{For Socrates,
                  philosophy is not like Christian conversion from
                  error to truth, but rather it is like the pagan
                  process whereby a young man is initiated into cult
                  mysteries by a more experienced
                  man\addthinspace--\addthinspace the
                  mystagogos\addthinspace--\addthinspace who prepares
                  him and leads him to the sacred precinct. In Greek
                  cult religion, the mystagogos prepared the initiate
                  for the esoteric mysteries revealed by the
                  hierophant. Socrates treats traditional wisdom with
                  scepticism, and this makes him appear ridiculous or
                  dangerous in the eyes of cultural
                  conservatives. Nevertheless, his scepticism is not
                  radical: custom is not something on which we must
                  turn our backs if we are to pursue the
                  truth. Socrates assumes an epistemology and employs
                  a method by which he induces his companions to begin
                  the critical and self-critical process of
                  philosophical inquiry, not ignoring conventional
                  wisdom, but thinking through and reinterpreting it
                  as they make constructive progress towards the
                  truth. He provides conclusive and convincing
                  arguments in support of controversial answers to
                  some of the most important moral questions he
                  poses.}}}

@Article{Adluri:Initiation,
  author =   {Vishwa Adluri},
  gender =   {sm},
  title =    {Initiation into the Mysteries},
  shorttitle =   {Initiation},
  langid =   {english},
  journaltitle = {Mouseion},
  year =     2006,
  issuetitle =   {\mkbibparens{Ir}rationality in the Ancient World},
  series =   3,
  volume =   6,
  number =   3,
  pages =    {407-423},
  eprint =   {http://digital.utpjournals.com/i/319761},
  annotation = {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
                sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
                At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
                Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est.},
  abstract =     {\mkbibquote{\selectlanguage{french}Les dialogues de Platon soulignent la
                  transformation personnelle et le salut tels qu'on
                  les trouvait dans \mkbibquote{l'initiation aux
                  mystères}. Burkert, Kingsley et Riedweg, en suivant
                  les traces de Damascius et des Néoplatoniciens, ont
                  récemment démontré les aspects théologiques,
                  existentiels et sotériologiques chez
                  Platon. Celui-ci exploite à son profit non seulement
                  le vocabulaire et l'organisation des rites
                  d'initiation mais aussi leur aspect
                  \mkbibquote{expérience vécue}. Ainsi Socrate: après
                  avoir désorienté ses interlocuteurs par la
                  dialectique, leur révèle les \mkbibquote{mystères}
                  au moyen de mythes grandioses qui représentent
                  rapogée de l'expérience philosophique. Celle-ci
                  confère une assurance intrépide devant la mort et
                  accorde le salut en montrant l'univers du point de
                  vue de l'éternelle raison
                  \mkbibparens{\mkbibemph{nous}}. Elle lave le
                  philosophe de toute identité politique et
                  idéologique.}}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{Adams:SocratesMystagogos,Adluri:Initiation,sigfridsson,worman,geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of bibliography with long abstracts.]